# Excluding boundaries using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap

I have round plots that include forest areas inside them (the picture is an example of one plot). I calculated the total perimeter of forest areas inside the plot. The problem is I want to exclude the plot boundaries that overlap with the forest.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. but when I convert to lines those boundries the plot boundries are still there.I want to calculate the edge effect. I want to get rid of the boundries of the plot that overlap the forest polygon. in the picture- I want to get rid of the black lines....
does that make sense? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpqSb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpqSb.png)

Comment: You could use Minimum Bounding Geometry to create a circle around your plot. Convert to line, Intersect or Clip with your plot and you will have the line length of the circle perimiter. Then subtract this from your original plots shape length

Answer (score -1):

1. convert the raster to polygons
2. union the polygon with the plot
3. select the polygon that are not forest (select by attribute)
4. delete the selected polygons (in an edit session)
5. use "polygon to line"
6. select all lines with either left of right FID = -1 (those are the forest/non forest boundaries)

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your forest to vector (if it is currently raster data) and run the [Erase geoprocessing tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/erase.htm), using your plots as the input and the forest as the erase coverage. Then, just recalculate the geometry of you plots on the output to get the area. One caveat though... this tool requires an Advanced license.